# Cannot show description of property that has type as class

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have a class with 4 properties like this

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of number property
    /// </summary>
    public int IntProp { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Description of string property
    /// </summary>
    public string StringProp { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Description of object property
    /// </summary>
    public AddressModel Address { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// List of object property
    /// </summary>
    public List<AddressModel> AddressList { get; set; }
```

I'm using Swagger to generate document for my Asp.Net Core API, below is the result

[image]

The description of **Address** property is missing, when checking the **swagger.json** file, I've noticed that **Address** property missing 'type'

[image]

I'm not sure what I missed. How can I show the missing description like the others? Can we hide the fullname of AddressModel and simply show it as 'object' instead?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sound like a bug on swagger-ui